# View the data inserted into Taffy Database

Tags: taffydb

I am using Taffy DB to store the data in my application.

I have inserted data inti Taffy DB like,

```
var teamList = TAFFY();
teamList.insert(data);
```

Now I want to check whether the data is inserted into the DB.

Please Advice

Answer (score 2):

To view data you need to use Taffy Query

try:

```
console.log(teamList().get());
```

Taffy query returns an array with data.

```
db().get(); // returns array with all stored data
```

You can use where in query like this:

```
db({column:value}).get(); - is like select * from table where column = value
```

> more info: http://www.taffydb.com/writingqueries

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`teamList.last();`

Returns the last record added.